# Passing null IdentityUser from one endpoint to another returns it as object

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

This is method which sends user:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                AppUser? user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.PhoneNumber);
                return RedirectToPage("VerifyCode", new
                {
                    phoneNumber = Input.PhoneNumber,
                    returnUrl = ReturnUrl,
                    appUser = user,
                    callbackType = SuccessCallbackType.SignInCallback
                });
            }

            return Page();
        }
```

This method in another class accepts user:

```
    public async Task OnGetAsync(string phoneNumber, string? returnUrl, AppUser? appUser, SuccessCallbackType callbackType)
    {
        AppUser = appUser;
        CallbackType = callbackType;
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
```

`appUser` parameter when passing null always contains an object with `PhoneNumber` set to `phoneNumber` parameter value. `AppUser` class is the successor of `IdentityUser` with additional properties.

Comment: If you check [the RedirectToPage constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pagebase.redirecttopage?view=aspnetcore-6.0), you will see that the only parameter you could pass data to another page is the `routeValued`,but you can't pass complex objects as route data. The route data feature only supports simple objects like int and string. If you want to retain more complex objects across requests, you need to use `Sessions` or `TempData`.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find where it's written in the documentation. Could you please paste a screenshot?

Comment: You can see the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybOAo.png). This is the only way you can redirect with data. Of course the document does not tell you it supports only simple type data, but from my long time learning, it does not work for complex object. If you agree, I will share more about how to use TempData or Sessions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect from Razor Page with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63452889/redirect-from-razor-page-with-data)

Comment: Yea, of course!